# Как запустить yolo v5?

Tags: python, numpy, cv2

Я пытаюсь научиться использовать yolo модельку с помощью гайда вот с этого сайта: https://medium.com/mlearning-ai/detecting-objects-with-yolov5-opencv-python-and-c-c7cf13d1483c

Тем не менее, несмотря на идентичный код (за исключением ресурсов), возникают ошибки. В чем может быть причина и как их устранить?

Код:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
```

## step 1 - load the model

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet('yolov5s.onnx')
```

## step 2 - feed a 640x640 image to get predictions

```
def format_yolov5(frame):
    row, col, _ = frame.shape
    _max = max(col, row)
    result = np.zeros((_max, _max, 3), np.uint8)
    result[0:row, 0:col] = frame
    return result


image = cv2.imread('bulletin.png')
input_image = format_yolov5(image)  # making the image square
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(input_image, 1 / 255.0, (640, 640), swapRB=True)
net.setInput(blob)
predictions = net.forward()
```

## step 3 - unwrap the predictions to get the object detections

```
class_ids = []
confidences = []
boxes = []

output_data = predictions[0]

image_width, image_height, _ = input_image.shape
x_factor = image_width / 640
y_factor = image_height / 640

for r in range(25200):
    row = output_data[r]
    confidence = row[4]
```

Здесь возникает ошибка

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
> ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

, которой не должно быть по логике кода, если я привильно понимаю. Поэтому приходится добавлять скобки и .any().

```
    if (confidence >= 0.4).any():
        classes_scores = row[5:]
```

Здесь также возникает ошибка, которую даже не знаю, как решить.

```
 cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\minmax.cpp:1498: error: (-215:Assertion failed) (cn == 1 && (_mask.empty() || _mask.type() == CV_8U)) || (cn > 1 && _mask.empty() && !minIdx && !maxIdx) in function 'cv::minMaxIdx'
```

```
        _, _, _, max_index = cv2.minMaxLoc(classes_scores)
        class_id = max_index[1]
        if classes_scores[class_id] > .25:
            confidences.append(confidence)

            class_ids.append(class_id)

            x, y, w, h = row[0].item(), row[1].item(), row[2].item(), row[3].item()
            left = int((x - 0.5 * w) * x_factor)
            top = int((y - 0.5 * h) * y_factor)
            width = int(w * x_factor)
            height = int(h * y_factor)
            box = np.array([left, top, width, height])
            boxes.append(box)

class_list = []
with open("classes.txt", "r") as f:
    class_list = [cname.strip() for cname in f.readlines()]

indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.25, 0.45)

result_class_ids = []
result_confidences = []
result_boxes = []

for i in indexes:
    result_confidences.append(confidences[i])
    result_class_ids.append(class_ids[i])
    result_boxes.append(boxes[i])

for i in range(len(result_class_ids)):
    box = result_boxes[i]
    class_id = result_class_ids[i]

    cv2.rectangle(image, box, (0, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (box[0], box[1] - 20), (box[0] + box[2], box[1]), (0, 255, 255), -1)
    cv2.putText(image, class_list[class_id], (box[0], box[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5, (0, 0, 0))

cv2.imwrite("misc/kids_detection.png", image)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте за основу [этот пример](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/yolo-screencapture-python), так как он уже работает. Поищите cfg файл [в этом репозитории в папке cfg](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/tree/master/cfg). Пока что, [там только четвертая версия](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/issues/2198)

```py
import numpy as np
import time
import cv2
import mss
import time

weightsPath = "./data/yolov3.weights"
configPath = "./data/yolov3.cfg"
labelsPath = "./data/coco.names"

np.random.seed()

LABELS = open(labelsPath).read().strip().split("\n")
COLORS = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(len(LABELS), 3),
    dtype="uint8")

print("[INFO] loading YOLO from disk...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(configPath, weightsPath)
# net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
# net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_OPENCL_FP16)

net.setPreferableBackend(cv2.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_CUDA)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CUDA)

layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
layer_names = [layer_names[i-1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

(W, H) = (None, None)

monitor = {"top": 25, "left": 0, "width": 1080, "height": 1080}
args = {"confidence" : 0.55, "threshold" : 0.3}

with mss.mss() as sct:

    while True:

        last_time = time.time()

        frame = np.array(sct.grab(monitor))
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)

        # construct a blob from the input frame and then perform a forward
        # pass of the YOLO object detector, giving us our bounding boxes
        # and associated probabilities
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(frame, 1 / 255.0, (416, 416), swapRB=False, crop=True)
        net.setInput(blob)
        start = time.time()
        layerOutputs = net.forward(layer_names)
        end = time.time()

        # initialize our lists of detected bounding boxes, confidences,
        # and class IDs, respectively
        boxes = []
        confidences = []
        classIDs = []

        # loop over each of the layer outputs
        for output in layerOutputs:
            # loop over each of the detections
            for detection in output:

                # extract the class ID and confidence (i.e., probability)
                # of the current object detection
                scores = detection[5:]
                classID = np.argmax(scores)
                confidence = scores[classID]

                # filter out weak predictions by ensuring the detected
                # probability is greater than the minimum probability
                if confidence > args["confidence"]:
                    # scale the bounding box coordinates back relative to
                    # the size of the image, keeping in mind that YOLO
                    # actually returns the center (x, y)-coordinates of
                    # the bounding box followed by the boxes' width and
                    # height

                    frameWidth = monitor["width"]
                    frameHeight = monitor["height"]

                    center_x = int(detection[0] * frameWidth)
                    center_y = int(detection[1] * frameHeight)
                    width = int(detection[2] * frameWidth)
                    height = int(detection[3] * frameHeight)
                    left = int(center_x - width / 2)
                    top = int(center_y - height / 2)
                    classIDs.append(classID)
                    confidences.append(float(confidence))
                    boxes.append([left, top, width, height])

        # apply non-maxima suppression to suppress weak, overlapping
        # bounding boxes
        idxs = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, args["confidence"],
            args["threshold"])

        # ensure at least one detection exists
        if len(idxs) > 0:
            # loop over the indexes we are keeping
            for i in idxs.flatten():
                # extract the bounding box coordinates
                
                (x, y) = (boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1])
                (w, h) = (boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3])

                # draw a bounding box rectangle and label on the frame
                color = [int(c) for c in COLORS[classIDs[i]]]
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
                text = "{}: {:.4f}".format(LABELS[classIDs[i]],
                    confidences[i])
                cv2.putText(frame, text, (x, y - 5),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, color, 2)
                
    
        print("[INFO] fps: {}".format(1 / (time.time() - last_time)))

        # frame = cv2.resize(frame,None,fx=0.7,fy=0.7)
        cv2.imshow("yolo",frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```